# JSON array from local file to Typescript array in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 5 to develop a web app. I have JSON file which looks like this:

```
[
  {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Some title"
  },
  {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Some title"
  },
  ...
]
```

This file is stored locally. I also have an interface:

```js
export interface Book {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

The questions are how do I:

1. Fetch the data from the file?
2. Create an array of type `Book[]` from this data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could load the file with `import`:

```
import data from 'path/to/data.json';
```

And assign that to an array of type `Book[]`:

```
@Component({...})
class Foo {
   books: Book[] = data;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcanua?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Also add a [wildcard module definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations) in `src/typings.d.ts` to tell the TypeScript compiler how to import `*.json`:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This answer could help someone, although it pertains to Typescript 4.(Angular 5 supports Typescript 2 ).

The sample JSON file content (data.json):

```
[
  {
    "Gender": "Male",
    "HeightCm": 171,
    "WeightKg": 96
  },
  {
    "Gender": "Male",
    "HeightCm": 161,
    "WeightKg": 85
  }
]
```

Appropriate `tsconfig.json` entry:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {  
      "esModuleInterop": true
      "resolveJsonModule": true
    } 
}
```

The code that reads the JSON content into an `interface` `Person`:

```
import data from './data.json';

interface Person{
    Gender: string,
    HeightCm: number,
    WeightKg: number
}

const personArray:Person[] = data as Person[];
```

Comment: the `esModuleInterOp` mark as `true` is required?

Comment: answer is correct, but `"esModuleInterop": true` config gave me errors in import

example : 
`import * as moment from "moment";`

to resolve errors, changed to
`import moment from "moment";`