# Iteration of json file in typescript in angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

```
[
        {
            "title": "Marker 1",
            "innercontent": "the Porcelain Factory"
        },
        {

            "title": "Marker 2",
            "innercontent": "The Taj Mahal "

        },
        {
            "title": "Marker 3",
            "innercontent": "Golconda Fort"
        }
]
```

The above is my json file.

```
<div *ngFor="let marker of currentmrkr">
      <div>
        {{ marker.title }}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ marker.innercontent }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

The above is my html file.

```
import * as content from './content.json';
marker.addListener("click", () => {for(let item of content){
            if(marker.getTitle() == item.title){
              this.currentmrkr = item;
            }
          }
}
```

The above is in my typescript file.

This shows an error like -

```
 core.js:6260 ERROR TypeError: _content_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___namespace is not iterable
```

How can we iterate through the json object inside the typescript file in angular and how to import the file into typescript?

Comment: You iterate the same like you do in js. By using some `for` loop or `forEach`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON array from local file to Typescript array in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797363/json-array-from-local-file-to-typescript-array-in-angular-5)

Comment: yes. After iterating where should i put the values so that i can access them in ngfor because ngfor is for arrays not for objects.

Comment: it is an array of objects.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to iterate JSON within Typescript logic for let's say pushing data to firebase, you can use library called [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

myfunction(json) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      _.map(json, (e, i) => {
       _.keys(e).map(() => {
        this.afs.collection('library').doc('doc ' + i).set(e);
       })
      })
     resolve();
   })
  }
```

I have a full [blog](https://medium.com/@theaaygupta/importing-data-from-csv-in-firestore-using-angular-9-5811e239b0b7) on this if you need more details. Else if you defined a simple json object in typescript and want to view particular value in HTML you can use the following approach:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-some-section",
  templateUrl: "./some-section.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./some-section.component.scss"],
})
export class SomeSectionComponent {
  users = [
    {
      name: "Jacob",
      job: "Analyst",
      city: "California",
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      job: "Founder",
      city: "New York",
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

}
```

and then in the HTML template:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let user of users">
    <h3 class="job">{{ user.job }}</h3>
    <h3 class="name">{{ user.name }}</h3>
    <h3 class="city">{{ user.city }}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your loadash logic is awesome. But i am getting an error u can see the error also.

Comment: Thanks @angularnoob, could you please share the details of your error? Maybe I can help.